# Pass a CharSequence to a Scanner in Java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, charsequence

The [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class has a constructor taking a `String`.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner( myString ) ;
```

How to feed a [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) object to a new `Scanner`? I could first generate a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) from the `CharSequence`, but that is inefficient and rather silly.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner( myCharSequence.toString() ) ;  // Workaround, but seems needlessly inefficient to instantiate a `String`.
```

I looking for a way to access the `CharSequence` directly from the `Scanner`. Something like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner( myCharSequence ) ;  // Use `CharSequence` directly.
```

The `Scanner` class also takes a `Readable` in a constructor. Can a `CharSequence` be presented as a `Readable`? Or is there some other workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the constructors *only* accept `String` and not the more generic `CharSequence`, you...can't.  Not unless you invoke `toString` on the `CharSequence`, anyway, which would get you a `String` back, which would satisfy the constructor's requirements.

So, the workaround calling [`CharSequence::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString()) as seen in the Question is indeed the way to go:

```
new Scanner( myCharSequence.toString() )
```

Comment: Okay. :-(  After reading your Answer, I edited to ask if a `CharSequence` might be presented as a `Readable` to satisfy another `Scanner` constructor.

Comment: [Javadoc says, "Nope"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Readable.html), since `Readable` not only doesn't give you back anything that'd represent a `CharSequence`, but it doesn't seem like it'd *really* be what you want, since `Readable` appears to deal with other stream-like entities.